# Calculate the number of records for each day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have user sign up. I want to display a graph for the last 7 days with the number of sign ups on each day based on the `created_at` record

Can i use active record query to achieve this with some kind of grouping and count instead of calculating it manually through iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_date` which will get rid of all time information, effectively leaving you with just the days.

`User.where('created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago).group_by { |u| u.created_at.to_date }.map { |_,v| [_, v.length]}.to_h`

OR, if you don't care about the time portion, you could use this:

`User.where('created_at >= ?', 1.week.ago).group(:created_at).count`

This will get you a  hash with the `created_at` and `count`.

Comment: is there a way i can just get the count?

Comment: `{2016-08-19 13:59:39 UTC=>1, 2016-08-19 07:30:24 UTC=>1, 2016-08-22 12:37:51 UTC=>1, 2016-08-19 07:23:36 UTC=>1, 2016-08-24 08:04:54 UTC=>1}` yeah looks like it takes time based. any way i can get it just based on the date. am using the second query

Comment: For a large number of records, that's certainly the fastest solution as the grouping is done in SQL and not pull all records and then group in ruby.

Comment: got it :) i think since i need it date based n not time. i think i will have to do with ruby version